# How to set number of plots in a page in R using multiplot?

Tags: r, plot, ggplot2

I'm trying to use multiplot() http://www.inside-r.org/packages/cran/rmisc/docs/multiplot to print multiple plots in a single page.

I create my plots' list using

```
for(i in 1:length(name_list)) {
    plot_obj <- ggplot(....) +
                geom_point() +
                stat_smooth()
    v[[i]] <- list(plot_obj)
}
```

Now when I use

```
pdf("Myplot.pdf"); multiplot(plotlist=v); dev.off();
```

all my plots are being cramped to the first page. Is there someway to control the number of rows of plots in each page? I know that number of columns can be controlled by cols parameter, but I'm looking how to change the number of rows.

Comment: in my unbiased view `gridExtra::marrangeGrob` is a better option

Comment: My totally (well, perhaps not) unbiased view is that `gridExtra::marrangeGrob` is a way better solution :-)